# Reading messages from Azure Service Bus queue with specific correlation id

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there any way of only receive messages from an Azure Service Bus queue with a specific correlation id?

The scenario is:

1. I am receiving a REST API call to my application A
2. My application A will generate an unique correlation id
3. My application A will send a request to another application B and include the correlation id. This request is *not* sent on the Azure Service Bus - with via another mechanism.
4. The application B will perform some logic and send a reply message on an Azure Service Bus queue with the correlation id it received in (3)
5. My application A wants to read only the message from the queue with the corresponding correlation id and generate a response to the initial caller based on this reply message.

I see that there is a concept of sessions, but it seems a bit overkill to create new sessions for each request to my application. I cannot reuse correlation id, because I need them to be unique for each request to my application. I see that an alternative could be to use a topic and subscribe with a filter, but that also seems like overkill.

Any ideas?

Comment: Explain how this will work? You don't want sessions, you can't use a correlation filter (requires a well-known value for that to work). Why do you care for a message sent from A to be received by B? Is there an instance-affinity in a scaled-out scenario? Do you have more than just one receiver B for the messages from A? Something is missing here to try to help with your scenario.

Comment: This is a simple request/reply pattern. Application A is sending a request to application B (including an correlation id). Application B is doing some work and responds with a reply message (with same correlation id set) on an Azure Service Bus queue. Application A will read the response from this queue - preferably just reading the message with the correct correlation id. I could let Application B set sessionid=correlation id and let Application A establish a session on this id, but it sounds that there would be some overhead...

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to correlate the response to a web request. Is that the case? I.e. a request over HTTP gets a response with the results of the processing from B, to the same HTTP requestor.

Comment: Why would filters not work for you ? you can add any custom property in all the events sent from any of the senders and then just have them read from specific subscriptions that apply those filters,  once those messages are sitting there if you wish not to read all of them ig you can lock them all and just process the desired ones and abandon the rest of them.